# dplyr mutate rowSums calculations or custom functions

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to mutate a new variable from sort of row calculation,
say `rowSums` as below

```
iris %>% 
  mutate_(sumVar = 
            iris %>% 
            select(Sepal.Length:Petal.Width) %>%
            rowSums)
```

the result is that "sumVar" is truncated to its first value(10.2):

```
Source: local data frame [150 x 6]
Groups: <by row>

   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species sumVar
1           5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa   10.2
2           4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa   10.2
3           4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa   10.2
4           4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa   10.2
5           5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa   10.2
6           5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa   10.2
..
Warning message:
Truncating vector to length 1
```

Should it be `rowwise` applied? Or what's the right verb to use in these kind of calculations.

**Edit:**

More specifically, is there any way to realize the inline custom function with `dplyr`?

I'm wondering if it is possible do something like:

```
iris %>% 
  mutate(sumVar = colsum_function(Sepal.Length:Petal.Width))
```

Comment: Really strange that `iris %>% select(Sepal.Length:Petal.Width) %>% rowSums()` works fine but `iris %>% mutate(sumVar = iris %>% select(Sepal.Length:Petal.Width) %>% rowSums())` throws a "Error: Bad indices 1" + warning message.

Comment: I am trying to work on it with different approaches, but this error appears very frequently using `.` (I am also doing something silly sometimes).

Comment: For operations like `sum` that already have an efficient vectorised row-wise alternative, the proper way is currently:  `df %>% mutate(total = rowSums(across(where(is.numeric))))` `across` can take anything that `select` can (e.g. `rowSums(across(Sepal.Length:Petal.Width))` also works). See the full spiel about [row-wise](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/rowwise.html) and [across](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/across.html)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use [`rowwise()`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/rowwise.html) function:

```
iris %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(sumVar = sum(c_across(Sepal.Length:Petal.Width)))

#> # A tibble: 150 x 6
#> # Rowwise: 
#>    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species sumVar
#>           <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl> <fct>    <dbl>
#>  1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2 setosa    10.2
#>  2          4.9         3            1.4         0.2 setosa     9.5
#>  3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2 setosa     9.4
#>  4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2 setosa     9.4
#>  5          5           3.6          1.4         0.2 setosa    10.2
#>  6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4 setosa    11.4
#>  7          4.6         3.4          1.4         0.3 setosa     9.7
#>  8          5           3.4          1.5         0.2 setosa    10.1
#>  9          4.4         2.9          1.4         0.2 setosa     8.9
#> 10          4.9         3.1          1.5         0.1 setosa     9.6
#> # ... with 140 more rows
```

"`c_across()` uses tidy selection syntax so you can to succinctly select many variables"'

Finally, if you want, you can use `%>% ungroup` at the end to exit from rowwise.

Comment: For operations like `sum` that already have an efficient vectorised row-wise alternative, the proper way is currently:  `df %>% mutate(total = rowSums(across(where(is.numeric))))` `across` can take anything that `select` can (e.g. `rowSums(across(Sepal.Length:Petal.Width))` also works). Scroll down the [row-wise](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/rowwise.html) vignette to find this and have a look at [across](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/across.html)

Comment: @FonsMA this should rather be an answer, and even an accepted answer, than a comment

Comment: @DanChaltiel, thanks, I didn't see the comment had this many upvotes! it's now an answer below

Answer (score 145):

This is more of a workaround but could be used

```
iris %>% mutate(sumVar = rowSums(.[1:4]))
```

---

As written in comments, you can also use a `select` inside of mutate to get the columns you want to sum up, for example

```
iris %>% 
  mutate(sumVar = rowSums(select(., contains("Sepal")))) %>% 
  head
```

or

```
iris %>% 
  mutate(sumVar = select(., contains("Sepal")) %>% rowSums()) %>% 
  head
```

Comment: Which version of `dplyr` are you using? When I try you example with `dplyr_0.4.1`, I receive an exception: `Error in is.data.frame(x) : object '.' not found`.

Comment: If it's of use to anyone, the reason why I was receiving the error `Error in is.data.frame(x) : object '.' not found` was because I had an old version of `magrittr`. When I updated from `magrittr_1.0.1` to `magrittr_1.5`, everything worked fine.

Comment: This very useful answer, I was wondering whether it would be possible to expand by using dplyr's **`match`** or **`contains`** instead of the `.[1:4]`?

Comment: @Konrad, you could do something like `iris %>% mutate(sumVar = rowSums(select(., contains("Sepal")))) %>% head` or `iris %>% mutate(sumVar = select(., contains("Sepal")) %>% rowSums()) %>% head`

Comment: @docendodiscimus Thanks very much for the useful comment.

Comment: The comment by @docendodiscimus really should be another (vote-able) answer.  It is the most robust dplyr-esque solution.

Comment: It's nice that this works, although Hadley says that a solution like this "works by coincidence, not by design. I wouldn't rely on it." But maybe it is supported now? Does anyone know?
https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/2050

Answer (score 12):

A more complicated way would be:

```
 iris %>% select(Sepal.Length:Petal.Width) %>%
mutate(sumVar = rowSums(.)) %>% left_join(iris)
```

Comment: Thanks Davide. `left_join` sounds a nice solution if using it with `by` key; however, it's not so robust and intuitive for this circumstance

Comment: I also worry the automatic "by" parameter selection in the join could cause some troubles.. the columns could contain non-unique values on some rows ..

Answer (score 11):

Adding @docendodiscimus's comment as an answer.  +1 to him!

```
iris %>% mutate(sumVar = rowSums(select(., contains("Sepal"))))
```

Answer (score 3):

I am using this simple solution, which is a more robust modification of the answer by Davide Passaretti:

```
iris %>% select(Sepal.Length:Petal.Width) %>%
  transmute(sumVar = rowSums(.)) %>% bind_cols(iris, .)
```

(But it requires a defined row order, which should be fine, unless you work with remote datasets perhaps..)

Comment: Hi could you please tell me the meaning of dot in between round brackets? ```rowSums(.)```

Comment: The dot represents the result coming out of the `%>%` pipe

Answer (score 3):

As requested, transforming my commment into an answer:

For operations like sum that already have an efficient vectorised row-wise alternative, the proper way is currently:

`df %>% mutate(total = rowSums(across(where(is.numeric))))`

`across` can take anything that `select` can (e.g. `rowSums(across(Sepal.Length:Petal.Width))` also works).

Scroll down the [row-wise](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/rowwise.html) vignette to find this and have a look at [across](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/across.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a grep in place of `contains` or `matches`, just in case you need to get fancy with the regular expressions (`matches` doesn't seem to much like negative lookaheads and the like in my experience).

```
iris %>% mutate(sumVar = rowSums(select(., grep("Sepal", names(.)))))
```