# How to use base::rowSums() with dplyr/magrittr pipe (%>%)

Tags: r, dplyr, magrittr

I am trying to answer how many fields in each row is less than 5 using a *pipe*. In the following form it works (without pipe):

```
rowSums(   iris[,1:4]  < 5  ) # works!
```

But, trying to ask the same question using a pipe does not work:

```
iris[1:5,1:4] %>%  rowSums(  . <5  ) # wrong: returns the total rowsum
iris[,1:4] %>%  rowSums(   < 5  )   # does not work either.
```

**Edit1**:
[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27354874/1831980) workaround by user 'docendo discimus' solves this:

```
iris %>% mutate(sumVar = rowSums(.[1:4]<5))
```

**Edit2**:
I like 'docendo discimus's workaround better because it avoids nested parenthesis:

```
iris %>%
  slice(1:5) %>%

  select(1:4) %>%

  dplyr::mutate( "New_var" = 10 ) %>% dplyr::mutate( "sumvar" = rowSums(. < 5 ) )
```

While the following solution (AFAICS) requires a nested parenthesis to work (plus I can't figure out how to  get the new column mutated on the dataframe)

```
(iris %>%
   slice(1:5) %>%

   select(1:4) %>%

   dplyr::mutate( "New_var" = 10 )  < 5 )  %>% rowSums(.)
```

Comment: try `iris[1:5,1:4] %>%  {rowSums(  . <5  )}`

Comment: @Khashaa you are right :) iris[1:5,1:4] %>% mutate( "newvar" = {rowSums( . <5 )} )
thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
iris[1:5, 1:4] %>% is_less_than(5) %>% rowSums
# 1 2 3 4 5 
# 3 4 4 4 3
```

would be `magrittr` equivalent to (no need in `dplyr` here)

```
rowSums(iris[1:5, 1:4] < 5)  
# 1 2 3 4 5 
# 3 4 4 4 3
```

Comment: full-pledged magrittr `iris %>% extract(1:5, 1:4) %>% is_less_than(5)%>% rowMeans`

Comment: A reason for the DV would be appreciated.