# Sum of sequence of columns inside pipeline

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a `data.frame` with about 2000 columns. How can I add sum of some subset of them to my `data.frame` using `%>%` operator?

Toy example

```
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)
set.seed(18)
X<-rnorm(100) %>% array(dim = c(5,20)) %>% data.frame %>% set_colnames(paste0('col',1:20))
```

I can calculate sum of columns 3-13:

```
X %>% select(col3:col13) %>% rowSums()
[1]  3,5471422  4,1526426 -3,6924671 -1,6106518 -0,6298387
```

But how to add it to `X`? This doesn't work:

```
X %>% mutate(col21=select(., col3:col13) %>% rowSums())
```

Of course

```
X$col21<-X %>% select(col3:col13) %>% rowSums()
```

works, but I really wish to use `mutate` or some other `dplyr` verb to allow for furher operations in one pipeline.

One more note: I'm aware of `num_range` function, but in real life column names are not `col1`, `col2`, ..., they can be anything, e.g `column`, `another.column`, `column3`.

Comment: Just as a tip: think about your data structure. A long-format might be much better for your purposes (and more "tidy")

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27354734/

Comment: @docendodiscimus: Long format is not perfect since in real life some of columns i my `data.frame` are not numbers. I usually have `sex`, `marital.status` etc. As to link ypou provided: all the anserws there deal with some patterns in column names. This is not my case. My column names can be anything and I don't want to use `.[,3:13]`-like  constructs because it's hadr to cound columns when you have 2000 of them.

Comment: @ŁukaszDeryło there are answers in the dupe that use names instead of indices of columns - For example [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27355197/5635580)

Comment: @Sotos Almost. `left_join` sollution changes order of columns. This is a trouble if I wanted to calculate then, say `col22`, as a sum of columns 10 to 15...

Comment: @ŁukaszDeryło, I have updated my answer in the linked post

Comment: `X %>% mutate(new = rowSums(select(., col3:col13)))` should do it (from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45864406/5635580))

Comment: @docendodiscimus You mean something like `X %>%   mutate(col21=rowSums(select(., col3:col13)))` ? This throws an error. And I can't use `contains` function because my column names do not have common part

Comment: @docendodiscimus My error is: `Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Each argument must yield either positive or negative integers`

Comment: If you don't have any pattern in your column names and you don't want to use indices, how do you want to select the column?

Comment: @docendodiscimus I konw the names of first and last column. Like form `ugly_named_column` to `malicious_melanoma`.

Comment: If you want to select columns by range (col3:col13) the above should work. If it does not check your structure. You may have non-numeric columns in there

Comment: Then you can use the following: `mtcars %>% mutate(x = rowSums(select(., cyl:qsec)))`. This works fine using dplyr 0.7.2

Comment: Sorry. This worked: `X %>%   mutate(col21=rowSums(select(., col3:col13)))` after third hit on Ctrl+R. I don't know what was wrong before. Thanks for help!

Comment: Not so great. Numbers added by `X %>% mutate(col21=rowSums(select(., col3:col13)))` are completely different than those from simple `X %>% select(col3:col13) %>% rowSums()` Plus a warning message `Warning messages:
1: In c(-1.88472709879316, 0.911427292224163, -1.30545587705056, 0.0420736502948709,  :
  numerical expression has 5 elements: only the first used`

Comment: @ŁukaszDeryło, we can't help you unless you provide a easily reproducible example. As mentioned, `mtcars %>% mutate(x = rowSums(select(., cyl:qsec)))` produces correct results

Comment: I updated `tidyverse` package. Now it works. Thanks once again.

Comment: My first sollution `X %>% mutate(col21=select(., col3:col13) %>% rowSums())` also works now...