# Recursively sum data frames for matching rows

Tags: r, dplyr, plyr

I would like to combine a set of data frames into a single data frame by summing columns that have matching variables (instead of appending columns).

For example, given

```
df1 <- data.frame(A = c(0,0,1,1,1,2,2), B = c(1,2,1,2,3,1,5), x = c(2,3,1,5,3,7,0))
df2 <- data.frame(A = c(0,1,1,2,2,2), B = c(1,1,3,2,4,5), x = c(4,8,4,1,0,3))
df3 <- data.frame(A = c(0,1,2), B = c(5,4,2), x = c(5,3,1))
```

I want to match by `"A"` and `"B"` and sum the values of `"x"`. For this example, I can get the desired result as follows:

```
library(plyr)
library(dplyr)
# rename columns so that join_all preserves them all:
colnames(df1)[3] <- "x1"
colnames(df2)[3] <- "x2"
colnames(df3)[3] <- "x3"
# join the data frames by matching "A" and "B" values:
res <- join_all(list(df1, df2, df3), by = c("A", "B"), type = "full")
# get the sums and drop superfluous columns:
arrange(res, A, B) %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(x = sum(x1, x2, x3, na.rm = TRUE)) %>% 
  select(A, B, x)
```

Result:

```
       A     B     x
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1     0     1     6
 2     0     2     3
 3     0     5     5
 4     1     1     9
 5     1     2     5
 6     1     3     7
 7     1     4     3
 8     2     1     7
 9     2     2     2
10     2     4     0
11     2     5     3
```

A more general solution is

```
library(dplyr)
# function to get the desired result for two data frames:
my_merge <- function(df1, df2)
{
  m1 <- merge(df1, df2, by = c("A", "B"), all = TRUE)
  m1 <- rowwise(res) %>% 
    mutate(x = sum(x.x, x.y, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
    select(A, B, x)
  return(m1)
}
l1 <- list(df2, df3) # omit the first data frame
res <- df1 # initial value of the result
for(df in l1) res <- my_merge(res, df) # call the function repeatedly
```

Is there a more efficient option for combining a large set of data frames? Ideally it should be recursive (i.e. it's better not to join all data frames into one massive data frame before calculating the sums).

Comment: If you are saying that `merge` or `full_join` is more memory efficient, it is okay, but I think the `rowwise` and later `sum` would be inefficient.  I would use `rowSums` or `reduce` with `+`

Comment: That's nice, thank you! So I could replace the second line in `my_merge` by `res <- res %>% mutate(x = rowSums(select(., x.x, x.y), na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
    select(A, B, x)` (as per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27354734/dplyr-mutate-rowsums-calculations-or-custom-functions).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easier option is to bind the rows of the datasets, then group by the columns of interest and get the summarised output by getting the `sum` of 'x'

```
library(tidyverse)
bind_rows(df1, df2, df3) %>% 
        group_by(A, B) %>%
        summarise(x = sum(x))
# A tibble: 11 x 3
# Groups:   A [?]
#       A     B     x
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     0     1     6
# 2     0     2     3
# 3     0     5     5
# 4     1     1     9
# 5     1     2     5
# 6     1     3     7
# 7     1     4     3
# 8     2     1     7
# 9     2     2     2
#10     2     4     0
#11     2     5     3
```

---

If there are many objects in the global environment with the pattern `"df"` followed by some digits

```
mget(ls(pattern= "^df\\d+")) %>%
        bind_rows %>%
        group_by(A, B) %>% 
        summarise(x = sum(x))
```

---

As the OP mentioned about `memory` constraints, if we do the `join` first and then use `rowSums` or `+` with `reduce`, it would be more efficient

```
mget(ls(pattern= "^df\\d+")) %>% 
      reduce(full_join, by = c("A", "B")) %>%
      transmute(A, B, x = rowSums(.[3:5], na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
      arrange(A, B)
#   A B x
#1  0 1 6
#2  0 2 3
#3  0 5 5
#4  1 1 9
#5  1 2 5
#6  1 3 7
#7  1 4 3
#8  2 1 7
#9  2 2 2
#10 2 4 0
#11 2 5 3
```

---

This could also be done with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
rbindlist(mget(ls(pattern= "^df\\d+")))[, .(x = sum(x)), by = .(A, B)]
```

Comment: Thanks! I considered `bind_rows` but doesn't it result in temporarily holding a (potentially huge) combined data frame in memory?

Comment: @rob I was thinking about the efficiency part

Comment: Fair enough. I guess it's hard to avoid a trade off between speed and memory usage.

Answer (score 2):

> Ideally it should be recursive (i.e. it's better not to join all data frames into one massive data frame before calculating the sums).

If you're memory constrained and willing to sacrifice speed (vs @akrun's data.table approach), use one table at a time in a loop:

```
library(data.table)
tabs = c("df1", "df2", "df3")

# enumerate all combos for the results table
# initializing sum to 0
res = CJ(A = 0:2, B = 1:5, x = 0)
# loop over tabs, adding on
for (i in seq_along(tabs)){
  tab = get(tabs[[i]])
  res[tab, on=.(A, B), x := x + i.x][]
  rm(tab)
}
```

If you need to read tables from disk, change `tabs` to file names and `get` to `fread` or whatever function.

I am skeptical that you can fit all the tables in memory, but cannot also fit an `rbind`-ed copy of them together.

---

Similarly (thanks to @akrun's comment), use his approach pairwise:

```
res = data.table(get(tabs[[1]]))[0L]

for (i in seq_along(tabs)){
  tab = get(tabs[[i]])
  res = rbind(res, tab)[, .(x = sum(x)), by=.(A,B)]
  rm(tab)
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Indeed I'm reading each data frame from a separate file, so the loop option is tempting. It's great to have a variety of options from you and @akrun to test out for optimal memory / speed.

Comment: @rob Cool :) Let us know (eg, via another answer) if you come up with another way. I'm not used to paying attention to RAM, so don't really know the best approach.