# Selecting rows with rowSums and mutate with dplyr error

Tags: r, dplyr

data:

```
head(well_being_df2)
# A tibble: 6 x 70
Age Gender  EmploymentStatus PWI1   PWI2   PWI3   PWI4   PWI5  PWI6 PWI7 Personality1 Personality2 Personality3  
<dbl> <dbl+l> <dbl+lbl>     <dbl+> <dbl+> <dbl+> <dbl+> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl+lbl>    <dbl+lbl>
```

I am selecting a subset of columns and trying to mutate them. I have played 
around with the solution provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27354734/dplyr-mutate-rowsums-calculations-or-custom-functions) but I am getting various errors. I am trying to select the PWI columns, then mutate with rowSums to a new variable called PWI_Index.

This works:

```
rowSums(select(well_being_df2, contains("PWI")))

[1] 50 32 48 32 58 52 41 51 49 37 50 53 58 47.... 
[38] 58 60 63 60 63 56 43 30 45 53 45 44 57 55.... 
[75] 50 55 57 58 57 58 58 58 62 62 44 59 58....
```

But then when I try to mutate:

```
mutate(well_being_df2, x = rowSums(select(well_being_df2, 
contains("PWI"))))
```

Which outputs/selects the entire set of columns not the "PWI" columns. Example:

```
# A tibble: 169 x 71
 Age Gender  EmploymentStatus PWI1   PWI2   PWI3   PWI4  PWI5  PWI6  PWI7  Personality1 Personality2 Personality3
 <dbl> <dbl+l> <dbl+lbl>        <dbl+> <dbl+> <dbl+> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl+lbl>    <dbl+lbl>    <dbl+lbl>   
 1  22   2       3                8      8      6      8     8     6    6     1            1            1    

 2  20   2       1                4      6      1      8     8     4     1     4            5            4
```

It selects the entire dataframe instead of the selected rowSums of "PWI". Using [.4:10] doesnt work either. Any other solution and I am getting the following error:

```
select(well_being_df2[.4:10]) %>%
mutate(PWI_Index = rowSums(.)) %>% left_join(well_being_df2)

Error: Column indexes must be integer, not 0.11, 1.11,...
```

Plus working through previous examples with:

```
well_being_df2 %>%
 mutate(x = rowSums(select(., contains("PWI")))) %>%
 head()
```

And it takes the entire set of columns like before.

Comment: @r2evans Accepted previous answers. Thought "upvote" meant acceptance.

Comment: Please add a reproducible example along with your expected output to make it easy for others to help you.

Comment: *edited - Hopefully a better explanation of what I am trying to do.

Comment: I was trying to print the selected new row to the console but my understanding of mutate was off... by a mile. The solution does work as @maurits-Evers outlined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand (or can reproduce) your issue.

Here is an example using the `iris` data that works just fine.

```
iris %>%
    mutate(x = rowSums(select(., contains("Width")))) %>%
    head()
#  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species   x
#1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa 3.7
#2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa 3.2
#3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa 3.4
#4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa 3.3
#5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa 3.8
#6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa 4.3
```

As you can see `x` is the sum of columns `Sepal.Width` and `Petal.Width`, and is the same as

```
rowSums(select(iris, contains("Width"))) %>% head()
#[1] 3.7 3.2 3.4 3.3 3.8 4.3
```

Comment: This only selects the first 6 entries not the entire set of observations for the selected columns.

Comment: @psych.tek That's because I *chose* to show only the first six entries with `head` for illustration purposes. Remove that line to get all, i.e. `iris %>%
    mutate(x = rowSums(select(., contains("Width"))))`. See basic `?head` for details.

Comment: ah ok. Bear with me, slowly getting my head around things. :) when i run: `rowSums(select(well_being_df2, contains("PWI")))` it works exactly as you have outlined. But when I run it inside mutate `mutate(well_being_df, x = rowSums(select(well_being_df2, contains("PWI"))))` it does not select the PWI but the entire set of rows. Thats where I am getting stuck.

Comment: Ok so it turns out my understanding of mutate is a little off. This does work but it was printing the entire set of columns  **including** the newly created(mutated) one.

Comment: @psych.tek Yup, it adds a new column `x` with entries based on the row sum across columns starting `"PWI"`. You got it;-)