# Compute row-wise counts using across or c_across

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, rowwise

I'd like to ask a  question inspired by  [this question asked years ago here in stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51783095/compute-row-wise-counts-in-subsets-of-columns-in-dplyr)

given the  data frame:
input_df

```
  num_col_1 num_col_2 text_col_1 text_col_2
1         1         4        yes        yes
2         2         5         no        yes
3         3         6         no       <NA>
```

this chunk of code

```
library(dplyr)    
df %>%
  mutate(sum_yes = rowSums(.[c("text_col_1", "text_col_2")] == "yes"))
```

will produce this new dataframe

```
> output_df
  num_col_1 num_col_2 text_col_1 text_col_2 sum_yes
1         1         4        yes        yes       2
2         2         5         no        yes       1
3         3         6         no       <NA>       0
```

The question is, how do you do the same with modern dplyr verbs *across* and *c_across*?

thank you.

Answer (score 3):

**1) c_across**  Here `c_across` returns a one row tibble containing the columns indicated by its argument.

```
library(dplyr)

input_df %>%
  rowwise %>%
  mutate(sum = sum( c_across(starts_with("text")) == "yes", na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
  ungroup
```

giving:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 5
  num_col_1 num_col_2 text_col_1 text_col_2   sum
      <int>     <int> <chr>      <chr>      <int>
1         1         4 yes        yes            2
2         2         5 no         yes            1
3         3         6 no         <NA>           0
```

**2) across**  This gives the same result.  `across` returns a tibble with only the columns indicated by its argument.

```
input_df %>%
  mutate(sum = rowSums( across(starts_with("text")) == "yes", na.rm = TRUE))
```

### Summing the scores for yes

In case it is of interest to sum the scores corresponding to the yes values:

**3) c_across**

```
library(dplyr)

input_df %>%
  rowwise %>%
  mutate(sum = sum( c_across(starts_with("num")) * 
    (c_across(starts_with("text")) == "yes"), na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
  ungroup
```

giving:

```
  # A tibble: 3 x 5
  num_col_1 num_col_2 text_col_1 text_col_2   sum
      <int>     <int> <chr>      <chr>      <int>
1         1         4 yes        yes            5
2         2         5 no         yes            5
3         3         6 no         <NA>           0
```

**4) across** The output is the same as (3).

```
input_df %>%
  mutate(sum = rowSums(across(starts_with("num")) * 
                 (across(starts_with("text")) == "yes"), na.rm = TRUE))
```

### Note

The input in reproducible form:

```
Lines <- "  num_col_1 num_col_2 text_col_1 text_col_2
1         1         4        yes        yes
2         2         5         no        yes
3         3         6         no         NA"
input_df <- read.table(text = Lines)
```